# Catching #REF errors in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-api

I am writing a program in the Google Spreadsheet API for Google App Script which references the display value cells in a sheet to formulate QUERY() functions, then returns the result of that formulated QUERY() function to different cells.

Because there are a lot of changing variables when formulating these query functions, (I am referencing a cell responsible for the source sheet, for the column to look for, and the data point to return,) the query functions which are formulated often have #REF or #N/A errors. Although this is easily avoidable for me, the program is intended for a client and I, therefore, have to have better-informed error messages so someone can easily figure out the issue.

[image]

In this case here, I am referencing the sheet "Utility Companies" for the column "Utility Name," then returning the corresponding "Address" value. because "Error" doesn't appear in the "Utility Name" column in the "Utility Companies" sheet, a #N/A error is thrown when trying to return the corresponding address.

I tried a try-catch statement, but it didn't seem to recognize an error:

```js
   try{
    //This is assigning the assembled QUERY() formula to a cell 
    //(works successfully & reliably)
      retrieveRange.getRange().getCell(k+1, 1).setFormula(formulaArray[k]);
    } catch (e){
    //Never catches an error, and therefor never logs the following-
      Logger.log("Error Recognized:" + e);
    }
```

How do I catch these errors? And furthermore, how do I report a custom error message for those errors?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that this thread might be useful for your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161874/detect-formula-errors-in-google-sheets-using-script

Comment: Thank you- this is a helpful function. However, I don't know how to return custom error messaging.

Comment: This can be easily solved with a helper column and an `if`.
First run the query on the helper column, then copy & paste the value of each cell in that column to your desired column with a loop. If cell value is "#REF!", write custom error for "#REF!" to destination, if cell value is "#N/A", write custom error for "#N/A" to destination...

Some working code : 
`var error = ss.getRange("E9").getValue()
  if(error == "#REF!") {
    ss.getRange("E10").setValue("REF")
  }
  else if (error == "#N/A") {
    ss.getRange("E10").setValue("N/A")
  }`

Comment: Try this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_i04M4N0bklEB29qcMBp2ba8P_FFDj-b1pOYz18_M8/edit?usp=sharing for your reference. Pasting these error from F1, G1, H1, I1 into K1 will generate a message corresponding to that error in E10.

Comment: @HaPhan Thank you- I like that helper column Idea to mitigate the errors showing up directly in the working column! It sounds like there isn't a more intuitive option to catch errors then- using a helper column is kind of a workaround. Is it possible to add custom error messages? When a ref error is in a cell and you hover over it, a possible message is "Query completed with an empty output." Is it possible to change that message with custom characters?

Comment: The reason your `catch` never work is because your `setFormula` function is always success. The error you received in the cell is not thrown by your code, but by Google Spreadsheet's function instead. I don't think there is any way to tinker with those popup, since they're built in, and currently there's really no function / script that allow one to modify them, Although there is a function called `ERROR.TYPE` which is a sheet function version of what I have written in the test sheet I shared with you.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you very much for your help! I'll use that sheet you sent me.