# Google Sheets Script: Search For Any Cell With Error

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling

In a spreadsheet I use almost 2M cells, which use a lot of functions, including ArrayFormulas etc spanning thousands of rows. Many columns do calcs based on previous columns that are also calc'd, so errors cascade.

Is there a way to do something like using createTextFinder(), but comparing a cell's contents to an array of ERROR.TYPEs?

Or is there no smarter way other than looping through all the cells? Although I can accomplish that, I'm sure there's a more efficient way to go about it.

Comment: If it's possible to get the contents of the error you could  try using a regular expression with the structure (Type1|Type2|....).  I don't know exactly what the regex would be but you can look at this [reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

Comment: Thanks, but regex confuses the hell out of me! However I did find a way to find errors in any column that ran fairly fast, considering the size of the ss.

Comment: At some point it confuses the hell out of most people, me included. But I've used it in array functions when I'm looking for different sorts of things from a list of items which sounded like something similar to what you were doing and it was quite good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect formula errors in Google Sheets using Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161874/detect-formula-errors-in-google-sheets-using-script)

Answer (score 3):

I found another post that I adapted, it finds errors in any column (not specific cell), but that's OK for my purposes, and doesn't take long to run:

```
function c_FindCellErrors() {
// Author: Max Hugen
// Date: 2021-01-09
// Purpose: Log all columns in spreadsheet with an error
// Source: Tedinoz
// Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848623/190925

  const aErrors = ["#NULL!", "#DIV/0!", "#VALUE!", "#REF!", "#NAME?", "#NUM!", "#N/A", "#ERROR!"];
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for ( i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if ( !sheet.getLastRow() || !sheet.getLastColumn() ) {continue; } // in case it's a blank sheet
    var dSheet = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    // loop though the columns
    for (var col=0; col<dSheet[0].length; col++){
      // create an array for the column
      var aCol = dSheet.map( function(getCol) { return getCol[col]; } );
      // loop through errors
      for (var errNum=0; errNum<aErrors.length; errNum++){
        // get the error
        var errVal = aErrors[errNum]
        // if the error exists in this column then response = true
        if (aCol.includes(errVal) == true){
          Logger.log('ERROR: Sheet: '+sheet.getName()+', Column: '+c_ColumnToLetter(col+1)+', Error: '+(errNum+1)+' - '+errVal);
  } } } }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Hi just one suggestion, i think it would be better if you start using  [IFERROR()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) in your formulas. I'm just concern with the execution time of your script if your data continues to grow. If you use Iferror() and set a default error string, it is easy to find using CTRL+F

Comment: Thanks Ron, yes I use iferror() in non-critical equations, but mostly I need to know the specific type of error and address it. Script took 18 secs for ~1.9M cells, which is quite acceptable - already found 2 errors that had eluded me. :)